# May have killed a cutting. Can dead plant cells be revived?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, botany

Ok. So, I went to New York City for the first time! My parents picked a hotel, and we had a good trip.

And even cooler, that hotel wasn't very far from a cool cedrus Atlantic a tree.

I got a cutting, but accidentally left in in the car today, and my mom went to work. The new growth has died. The old hardened-off growth still exists, but may or may not be dead.

It's evergreen, and it's not easy to tell.

So, assuming it is dead, and since it will be a long time till my next family trip, how could I bring one of the cells back to life, so I can generate explants?

Obviously this is very hard to do with animal cells, but could it be different with plant cells?

Could I just collect a bunch of dead cells, and pour atp solution on them?

Could I perform a nuclear transfer?

How could this be done?

And most importantly, CAN this be done?

Comment: Are you asking how to clone an evergreen? Or do you want to revive dead plant cells? For the second, reading Frankenstein might be useful :P

Comment: #2. And frankenstein won't work.

Comment: Making viable cutting from trees can already be tricky and difficult, you need to cut the right part of the tree and at the right time of the year. Reviving dead cells is impossible. Only possible in movies (Jurassic Park, Frankenstein, night of the living dead, etc.)

Comment: Nuclear transfer?

Comment: Nuclear transfer is used with viable cells, and even then this is very difficult. You'll need a hi-tech lab with highly skilled personnel. To revive dead cells is really sci-fi.